# Random fragment gets updated with setText

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i have an Android project with one activity and three fragments. All the fragments have the same view items on them. It is based on the TabbedActivity sample project. This creates multiple instances of the same fragment view.

All of the editboxes have the same id:
android:id="@+id/editText2"

The fragments have THE SAME button and THE SAME editbox on them, Pressing on the button starts a network activity which tries to update the editbox on the same fragment.

```
    final EditText resultBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    System.out.println("reponse: " + decodedStr);
    try 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            resultBox.setText(decodedStr);
        }
         });
    }
```

But only one of the fragments gets updated, and it is sometimes not even the active one. What exactly happens here when i do the findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Edit: added more code, turns out that the getText function gets the wrong data as well:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }



    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_PAGE_TITLE = "page_title";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(String pageTitle) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PAGE_TITLE, pageTitle);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getString(ARG_PAGE_TITLE)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            String pageTitle;
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    pageTitle = "1";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pageTitle = "2";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pageTitle = "3";
                    break;
                default:
                    pageTitle = "4";
                    break;
            }
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(pageTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void randomFunc(View view) {
        try {

            // Get the current Fragment in View using the ViewPager's currentItem
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = (PlaceholderFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            // Get the current Fragment's View
            View fragview = fragment.getView(); // Same view that onCreateView returns
            System.out.println("fragView " + fragview); // NULL

            EditText et = (EditText) fragview.findViewById(R.id.editText); // CRASH!!

...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("func failed" + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

and in xml:

android:onClick="randomFunc"

Comment: final EditText resultBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); could be changed to final EditText resultBox = (EditText) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Comment: why don't you create a class member variable reference of edittext view and then use in on run method ! what happen when you do findViewById is it will do BFS traversal of your hierarchy tree from View you init the findViewById

Comment: Please paste the Activity and fragment code where you are updating the EditText .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your using a ViewPager so in order to update the correct fragment do:

```
// Get the current Fragment in View using the ViewPager's currentItem
PlaceholderFragment fragment = (PlaceholderFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
// Get the current Fragment's View
View view = fragment.getView();
// Find the view your looking for, and update its text
final EditText resultBox = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
try {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        resultBox.setText(decodedStr);
    }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, i was indeed using the ViewPager. I tried the example above but for some reason the fragment.getView() returns null.

What could cause this? 

The onCreateView function returns a rootView which is not null.

Comment: @elelont can you post your Activity and Fragment code, with the Network code your using, or create a gist and share the url

Comment: @elelont this fragment view is returning null because you left the boiler plate code which always returns a new instance of the fragment when getItem is called, which on instantiation has no view associated because the onCreateView callback is not be invoked right away. You should instead create a List<Fragment> and keep track of the Fragments instead there and return the Fragment at the given index instead of rely on the boilerplate code

Comment: Okay, got it now. But should it not be the FragmentManager that keeps track or the fragments?

Comment: @elelont the fragment manager does keep track of the Fragments yes, but since you are always returning a new Instance of the Fragment it is managing those instead of existing Fragments

Comment: Hmm, im still confused here. If the FragmentManager does keep track of the fragment instances then why do i need to create a list of the fragments myself. Can't i just ask for a fragment at a given index?